# How to modify layout for ADF advance search?

Tags: layout, button, oracle-adf, advanced-search

I have an ADF page that have advance search function. Advance search have collapse panel on top of it that give the ability to user to collapse or expand the search function and have button for "reset" or search at the right. But currently my client want me to change it. They want me to :

```
1. remove/hide  "Search" colapse panel so that user cannot hide/adjust it.Currently,  I use display mode=default.

2. Move button for "search" and "reset" to the left.
```

Is there a way for me to adjust this?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to change the location of the buttons using skinning:
http://jdevadf.oracle.com/adf-richclient-demo/faces/components/skinningKeys/query.jspx